# Save Taxonomy of Post via custom Taxonomy Select Dropdown

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "nutrix-recipe".

It has a lot of taxonomies, for example "nutrix-category" or "nutrix-tag".

In post_edit.php, I removed all taxonomy meta boxes and added select2 fields to allow selection of terms. This works so far. The meta is saved.

This is, for example, how nurix-category is displayed inside the display_metbox function:

```
// CATEGORIES FIELD
    $html = '';  
    $label = __( 'Category: ', 'nutrix' );
    $current_tags = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'nutrix_select2_categories',true );

    if( $categories = get_terms( 'nutrix-category', 'hide_empty=0' ) ) {
        $html .= '<div class="nutrix-div-20"><p><label for="nutrix_select2_categories">' . $label . '</label><br /><select id="nutrix_select2_categories" name="nutrix_select2_categories[]" >';
        foreach( $categories as $category ) {
            $selected = ( is_array( $current_tags ) && in_array( $category->term_id, $current_tags ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            $html .= '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '"' . $selected . '>' . $category->name . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select></p></div>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

This is the nutrix-tag display:

```
// TAGS FIELD
     $html = '';  
     $label = __( 'Tags: ', 'nutrix' );    
     $current_tags = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'nutrix_select2_tags',true );
    if( $tags = get_terms( 'nutrix-tag', 'hide_empty=0' ) ) {
        $html .= '<div class="nutrix-div-40"><p><label for="nutrix_select2_tags">' . $label . '</label><br /><select id="nutrix_select2_tags" name="nutrix_select2_tags[]" multiple="multiple" >';
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
            $selected = ( is_array( $current_tags ) && in_array( $tag->term_id, $current_tags ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            $html .= '<option value="' . $tag->term_id . '"' . $selected . '>' . $tag->name . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select></p></div>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

I save them this way (nonce is missing atm):

```
function nutrix_save_recipe_mb( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    // if post type is different from our selected one, do nothing
    if ( $post->post_type == 'nutrix-recipe' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['nutrix_select2_categories'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'nutrix_select2_categories', $_POST['nutrix_select2_categories'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'nutrix_select2_categories' );

        if( isset( $_POST['nutrix_select2_tags'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'nutrix_select2_tags', $_POST['nutrix_select2_tags'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'nutrix_select2_tags' );
}
}
```

All these work. But my problem is, that the taxonomy terms are not assigned to the post. Or from another view:
If I visit the edit tags page, the category count remains zero.

Is it possible to not only save the meta, but also set the taxonomies ?

Thank you :)

[image: looks a lot better than standard taxonomy boxes]

Comment: Why do you store these as meta? As long as the input names and values match WP will happily store the terms without realising it's a different UI. If you need those values on the frontend, there are functions and APIs for retrieving them. Perhaps if you added some context for why you need them as post meta that would help, but I see no advantage, it's unnecessary, and if you're filtering/sorting by these post meta values, then that's going to be a **major** performance hit compared to using taxonomies and terms

Comment: Basicly because I am a beginner in coding and because the taxonomy selection via meta fields is part of the interface when creating a recipe. As you can see, the select boxes query the taxonomy terms. If there is a way how I can save the values without creating additional meta terms, feel welcome to show me this. From my (very basic) knowledge, that means that I have to not update post meta but save the terms, right? But I don´t know how.

Comment: You don't have to save the terms yourself, though you could have asked how to do that. Just make sure the HTML form values look the same in `POST`, and WordPress will use the same code it uses for the default taxonomy box to save them. It doesn't know what the HTML looks like, just what it sees in the request, so as long as you put the right names and values, it doesn't matter if the tags are completely different.

Comment: Not sure if I really understand that. As said, the select2 boxes query the taxonomy terms. This means, that the select2 options are exactly like the term names of the corresponding taxonomy. So, my task here, is to no save the selected values as terms in "post_meta" table, but just set the taxonomy for the post. And I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: If I have `<input name="foo" value="bar"` and code that saves that name/value, it will work regardless of wether the type if `text` or `number`, or if it's a `<select name="foo">` tag with exactly the same name and value. The same is true of the taxonomy selection UI. If you give the input your select2 input the same name as what Core gives the checkbox/input fields, then it won't know the difference between your custom UI, and the default UI

Comment: Otherwise, your question isn't really about post meta, it's how to replace the taxonomy ui with a `select2` control, you should update it to reflect that

Comment: updated the post name and tags. And how, with my above mentioned select boxes, can I set the post terms based on the selection?

Comment: If you've set the names correctly, WP will do it for you, no extra code necessary. Why are you swapping out the UI for a `select2` anyway? Does it not cause accessibility problems?

Comment: Well, but it doesn´t. It saved meta values to given meta keys, but it does not do "set_object_terms" to assign the categories selected to the post. For your interest, I added a screenshot to the above post to show what I mean with "better UI". I want to create post form in frontend and with this markup, i can do the same on both, back and frontend.

Comment: Ok but realise that `nutrix_select2_tags` wouldn't work for this, it would have to be something like `tax_query[nutrix-category]` as the `name` of the input. As an aside, wouldn't it make more sense to have multiple metaboxes, e.g. an Ingredients metabox, a steps metabox, etc

Comment: For the meta boxes… mhm.. maybe. just a design decision. Thanks for your hint with tax_query[nutrix-category]. even I don´t really know what you mean here. OK, I understand, for multiple select it should be an array… but the meta is already saved as it is in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm referring to the name of the input, e.g. `<input name="tax_query[nutri....`, you really should take a look at the markup the default WP metabox generates